Is there any app or website which I can integrate in my own website/app where user can visualize room's wall colors and tiles and other decorations
I'm looking for an online, free app or platform where I can upload photos of a room and experiment with different wall colors, floor tiles, window and door styles, and other decorative elements. The goal is to provide a visual demonstration of these changes before making physical alterations.
Specific Requirements:

Image Upload: Ability to upload photos of a room to serve as a base for the design experiment.

Color Palette: A wide range of color options for walls, including customizable shades and tones.

Tile Selection: A variety of tile patterns and textures to choose from for flooring.

Window and Door Styles: Options for different window and door styles, materials, and finishes.

Decorative Elements: The ability to add or remove decorative elements like furniture, plants, and artwork.

Real-time Visualization: Instantaneous updates to the room's appearance as changes are made.

User-Friendly Interface: A simple and intuitive interface that is easy for non-technical users to navigate.

Free or Low-Cost: Ideally, the app or platform should be free or offer a low-cost subscription model.



You seem to be asking for a recommendation for a resource. This is off-topic for stackoverflow. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow..."
